# Class path resource cannot be opened on an already working application

Tags: java, spring, websphere, freemarker

This is a fairly common exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [abc.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

However our application is able to find this resource, read it and work perfectly over a period of time and then this exception occurs i.e. for the same resource which was accessible earlier on.

Is there a possibility of resources being removed from the classpath? There are no traces of such an activity (server stop or start, or new deployments or war / jar updates) on the server.

Our environment is IBM Websphere running over Linux and this resource is being accessed by the Freemarker framework running over Spring container. Can there be a bug in either any of these frameworks or (more likely) some activity performed on the application server which can cause this?

More stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [abc.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157) ~[spring-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader.getReader(SpringTemplateLoader.java:77) ~[spring-context-support-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:413) ~[freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:330) ~[freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:205) ~[freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:740) ~[freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665) ~[freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
```

Comment: classpath resources should be considered immutable/readonly items. So no they should not disappear on you. However likely you are reading an exploded war/ear which turns out to be just a file, so it is theoretically possible that some process is deleting it, altho highly unlikely. in all cases though, i would highly recommend using absolute paths to your resources, not relative ones.

Comment: Why don't you put a file watcher on the file? if it disappears you would know when

Comment: In one case where I have found similar problem (templates disappearing after a while) the cause was that the Servlet container has extracted the war to a temporary directory from which old files were periodically deleted by some cron job.

Comment: Reading the comments it seems that we can establish that deletion by an external process is a possibility, however my confusion in that regards is that will it be allowed by the OS while the application server is running?

Comment: The OS doesn't know that the files are belonging to running application. It knows if a file is opened, but the template files are normally rarely opened and even then only for a moment. (Also, deleting opened files is usually allowed on Linux. But it's quite irrelevant here.)

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue on my own Webshpere (which is on Windows) and was able to delete the files, which has to do more with how freemarker uses the templates (it has some caching logic) but doing so did not reproduce the exception for me. Again, it might be how freemarker / spring behave, perhaps they reload the files after a particular time. So yeah, still unable to pinpoint the root cause other than speculating that it 'might' be due to files deletion by an external application.